# Swift: applicationDidEnterBackground timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I need to add an NSTimer in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method; I tried adding

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("test"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What does your `test` method look like? For what purpose are you using NSTimer and why do you need it?

Comment: my test:     func test() {println("asd");} i need get location i background

Comment: After a certain period of time?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, your declaration should look something like this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self, selector: "test:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Note two things:

1. You can pass a string literal to the selector parameter directly (no need for `Selector()` syntax), but this is of course optional.
2. The NSTimer expects the selector that will fire when it hits zero to accept a parameter (of type `NSTimer`) to which it will pass itself, so a colon (`:`) is needed at the end of the selector name to indicate that it will take a parameter.

   > The selector should have the following signature: `timerFireMethod:`
   >   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The
   >   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
   >   following pattern: `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer`

   <sub>From the [`NSTimer` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:).</sub>

   Because of this, you'll also have to modify your function declaration a bit:

   ```
   func test(timer: NSTimer) {
       // Proceed to grab location from background
   }
   ```