# Text to speech in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background, text-to-speech

I am playing a bit of text to speech every x amount of seconds e.g. every 20 seconds, and want this to keep going in the background when the app is closed.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? I have seen other apps that do this.

Comment: which app you seen that.. it is working after it terminated.

Comment: Try inserting your code in func applicationDidEnterBackground. This function is present in AppDelegate.swift file.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Seconds Interval Timer HIIT

Comment: @Saurabh How will this make any difference?

Comment: @D-AUK Yeah u r right, it is working. Basically it is working on the background thread as Saurabh said. A/c to apple, app can work in background only for apprx 10 mints after that it will be automatically killed. If app is terminated you cant do this.

Comment: It will help you to run the code in the background. Did you try entering the code in the mentioned function?

Comment: I am doing that right now I will let you know once done and whether it worked or not - thanks! :)

Comment: Hi how do I use NSTimer inside the applicationDidEnterBackground function?

Comment: Refer this link for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/28840510/5255016